# Splitting rows in a dataframe into 2 lines

Tags: r

I have string which I wish to split up, the string will always look like this;

```
 No.         Name                    Country
 100/200     name-one/name-two       SPA/FRA
```

I want this to look like;

```
100  name-one SPA
200  name-two  FRA
```

It might be worth adding that this is inside a dataframe which overall will look like this; I just need to unsplit the rows which look like this

big dataframe example, so i basically just want to split every row with a '/' onto 2 separate rows

```
100  name-one SPA
200  name-two  FRA
100/200     name-one/name-two       SPA/FRA
100  name-one SPA
200  name-two  FRA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, you can do it with `separate_rows`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  separate_rows(everything(), sep = "/")
```

*or* in `base R`:

```
lapply(df, function(x) strsplit(x, "/"))
```

Answer (score 1):

use `tidyr::seperate_rows`:

```
tidyr::separate_rows(df, V1, V2,V3, sep="/")
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  V1    V2       V3   
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>
1 100   name-one SPA  
2 200   name-two FRA  
3 100   name-one SPA  
4 200   name-two FRA  
5 100   name-one SPA  
6 200   name-two FRA
```

Note: you can also replace `V1,V2,V3` with `everything()`